# Get pages from MediaWiki API using jQuery

Tags: jquery, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I've been trying to come up with a solution to get links/pages (dunno what it's called) from a MediaWiki category page using simple jQuery. I'm been reading the [API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API) docs but don't really know what to look for.

If you look at [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aUpcoming_video_games) you'll see release dates for video games.. that's the information I want to obtain. And this is as far as I got:

```
var title="Upcoming_video_games";

$.getJSON("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=allpages&titles="+title+"&format=json&callback=?", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Does someone know how to do this? Any help is appreciated.

TIA

Comment: It looks like the actual release date is not on that page. Do you want to dive into each page to find the release date, or do you just want the list of games on the category page?

Comment: @Andrew: Oh I see. The basic information I want is release date, name and console, so yeah, probably dive into each page. But how would that affect the performance?

Comment: Negatively: You will have to follow links on the categories page to each article, and then extract the information you need.

Comment: You could try [DbPedia](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=SELECT+%3Ftitle+%3Fdate+%3Fplatform%0D%0AWHERE+{%0D%0A++++%3Fgame+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fterms%2Fsubject%3E+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FCategory%3AUpcoming_video_games%3E+.%0D%0A++++%3Fgame+foaf%3Aname+%3Ftitle+.%0D%0A++++%3Fgame+dbpprop%3Areleased+%3Fdate+.%0D%0A++++%3Fgame+dbpprop%3Aplatform+%3Fplatform+.%0D%0A}%0D%0AORDER+by+%3Ftitle%0D%0A).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&callback=?";
var page = "Pune"; // your page title, eg. New_York

$.getJSON(url, { 
  page: page, 
  limit:1,
  prop:"text|images", 
  uselang:"en"
}, function(data) {
  var $container = $("body")

  // append body
  //$container.append(data['parse']['text']['*']);
```

Then get data in var and use find function each object like images, title, or some tags..
Abhijeet...